# How can I add an average bar to bar chart in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2012

I have created a report with a bar chart which the boss was so happy with he asked me to add some things to it. One thing I cant seem to figure out is he would like a bar at the end of the report with the average. I suggested adding a calculated series for the average which was promptly shot down. Has anyone created an extra bar at the end of a chart? if so how did you go about doing it?

I am including my query and A screenshot of my chart.

```
SELECT        fcompany, fnnumber, Year, ShipQty, RMAQty, PercentReturned, DPPM
FROM            CustomerCalculations
```

[image]

Comment: Can't you just add another period to your chart (by modifying your dataset) which will contain the average value you need to have?

Comment: That's a good point I will look at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another bar chart on top of the existing chart, off to the right-hand side, using `AVG(Fields!DPPM.Value)` as the value. This would allow you to make that bar a different color, to differentiate it from the period-grouped bars.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to use something very similar to what you suggested..AVG(Sum(Fields!DPPM.Value)).